# If $x$ is real, does that mean every equation containing $x$ has real roots?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, conic-sections, parametric

### Question

If the normal to the parabola $y^2 = 4ax $ at the point $(at^2,2at)$ cuts the parabola again at $(aT^2,aT)$ , then prove that $T^2 \ge 8$.

### Answer

Normal at $(at^2,2at)$ is $y+tx=2at+at^3$, which cuts the parabola again at $(aT^2,2aT)$, resulting in the following:
$$ 2a(T-t)=-at(T^2-t^2)$$
$$ \implies 2=-t(T+t)$$
$$ \implies t^2+tT+2=0$$

My doubt starts here:

Since $t$ is real, $T^2-8 \ge 0$ which proves $T^2 \ge 8$.

But if $t$ is real does that *necessarily* imply that any equation it forms has only real roots?

Comment: What do you mean by calling a variable "real"?

Comment: All of your objects are real. Your parabola lives in $\Bbb{R}^2$, as does the normal line at $(at^2, 2at) \in \Bbb{R}^2$. If you need a point outside of $\Bbb{R}^2$ for the equations of the normal line and the parabola to agree, then the line and the parabola do not intersect. If you extended these objects into $\Bbb{C}^2$, then they definitely will intersect, but that's not the question here.

Comment: $x=1$ is real, and $x=1$ satisfies the equation $x^3=1$. However, $x^3=1$ also has two non-real roots: $\frac12(-1\pm i\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: Your point $(aT^2,aT)$ does not lie on the parabola. Did you mean $(aT^2,2aT)$ similar to the first point?

Comment: @LutzLehmann , yes. Edited now

Comment: @Blue , I was thinking of a similar example. Does this work (all roots real) in this case because the degree is 2?

Comment: @PandaScientist: *"Does this work (all roots real) in this case because the degree is $2$?"* ...  If you're limiting the scope of "equations" under discussion to *polynomials with real coefficients*, then ... yes: If one root of a degree-$2$ polynomial is real, then so is the other. This is because any non-real roots of a polynomial with real coefficients occur in complex-conjugate pairs $a\pm bi$ (with $b\neq0$). Since the total number of roots is equal to the polynomial's degree, a quadratic doesn't have seats available for a real root and a conjugate pair.

Comment: @Blue , thank you :-) I got it!